# Azure Webapp cannot connect to external FTP

Tags: asp.net, azure, hosting, azure-web-app-service, ftp-client

We've got a webapp that needs to connect an external ftp to download files.

All the prog works fine on the staging environment. However on azure hosting the ftp connect fails.

Examining the FTP server log we found out that th application tries to set the datachannel port using an internal azure IP (100.xxx.xxx.xxx) instead of one the public application IPs (65.12x.xxx.xxx) so the FtpWebRequest fails with timeout since the server tries to connect to an unaccessible recipient.

How can we configure the application so it dialogs with the external FTP server using a public IP adress?

Thanks for any insight.

Max.

Comment: I'm surprised that the IP of the FTP client matters. How is it different from doing this from a local machine that doesn't have a public IP (i.e. behind some proxy)?

Comment: Actually the IP of the client matters in the command it sends to the server to establish the datachannel socket. In the case of the azure webapp, the FtpWebRequest instance issues a PORT 100.xxx.xxx.xxx... ftp command to the remote server instead of a PORT 65.12x.xxx.xxx... to get a socket to download the files